# How to edit a Table Block of wagtail page and save to the DB

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

My wagtail page body is a StreamField and there are multiple blocks in it and one of which is TableBlock(). I want to edit the text inside the table and save it to the DB. My current approach is fetching the body and converting it into a string, and editing the text, then converting to a TableBlock() and saving it. However, this approach isn't successful.

```
body = page.body

for i,block in enumerate(body):
   table_content = str(block.value)
   if block.block_type == 'table':
      table_content = table_content.replace("string1","string2")
      body[i] = ('table', TableBlock(table_content))

page.body = body
page.save()
```

Is there a way to edit the text? any leads are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to edit the text inside the table which is saved as a Table Block of wagtail page. Here I have mentioned my current approach, where I am fetching the body of the page and from that I am converting the block to string to edit it. I hope this is clear